# Tampermonkey script update logic

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm developing a userscript that runs continuously on a remote machine and needs to be up to date.

However, when the script auto-updates, it needs to reload the page to apply the update, so my script is also trying to predict when the update will happen, so that it can refresh the page afterwards.

This has proven to be difficult though: even though I set the period to the minimum of six hours, the script usually updates seven or more hours after it was last updated.

So how does the logic for uodates work? Is there a hook or a callback that I can use to reload the page after the update, in order to apply it? Or do you have some other tip for predicting the time the script will update more precisely?

Here's the logic I currently use to do this:

```
function monitorScriptUpdates() {
    informUserIfScriptUpdated();
    var updateTimerSet = false;

    var timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (updateTimerSet) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        } else {
            checkForUpdates();
        }
    }, 60000);

    function checkForUpdates() {
        getNewestScriptVersion().then((newestVersion) => {
            const actualScriptVersion = GM_info.script.version;

            if (actualScriptVersion >= newestVersion) {
                return;
            }

            const currentTimeInMs = Date.now();
            const scriptLastUpdatedMs = GM_info.script.lastModified;
            const msSinceTheLastUpdate = currentTimeInMs - scriptLastUpdatedMs;
            const sixHoursInMs = 21600000;
            const fiftyMinutesBuffer = 3000000;

            updateTimerSet = true;
            if (localStorage.getItem('updateAttempted')) {
                localStorage.removeItem('updateAttempted');
                console.log('Automatic update failed, possibly because the update period is set to more than 6 hours! Disabling update check.');
                return;
            }

            const timeUntilUpdateIsAvailable = (sixHoursInMs - (msSinceTheLastUpdate % sixHoursInMs)) + fiftyMinutesBuffer;
            console.log('New script version detected! Automatic update will be attempted on ' + new Date(Date.now() + timeUntilUpdateIsAvailable));
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('Update should be available if the update period is set to 6 hours. Reloading...');
                localStorage.setItem('updateAttempted', true);
                location.reload();
            }, timeUntilUpdateIsAvailable);
        });
    }

    function informUserIfScriptUpdated() {
        var lastRecordedVersion = localStorage.getItem('scriptVersion');
        var actualScriptVersion = GM_info.script.version;

        if (lastRecordedVersion && lastRecordedVersion != actualScriptVersion) {
            localStorage.removeItem('updateAttempted');
            console.log('Script updated successfully from version ' + lastRecordedVersion + ' to version ' + actualScriptVersion);
        }

        localStorage.setItem('scriptVersion', actualScriptVersion);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Dusan

Comment: Is it possible that the delayed update is related to whether the page is the active/focused tab or not? When tab does not have the focus, it greatly slows down loop iterations.

Comment: ....I seem to have completely misunderstood what this post was about. What you're saying is, *"Even after I upload my new changes, my old version of the script is still cached, and so refreshing the page gives me my old version of the script."* ...Which is completely unrelated to **Tampermonkey**. Which server are you storing your script on? Perhaps it's as simple as clearing your browser cache? (Or disabling cache in your browser.) Or perhaps you need to clear your CDN cache?

Comment: @EliezerBerlin, no, that's not true either. I update the script, I can see the updated script on github. After a minute my script visits the github file and finds out that there's new update. However it can't do anything about it until tampermonkey updates the script. After tampermonkey updates the script (which should happen every 6 hours), the new version wilo not kick in until the page is reloaded, which means my script needs to rwload the page, but it has to be after tm has updated it. Apparently, figuring out when will tm update the script is very hard. That's what I asked

Answer (score 0):

What you describe really does sound like the tab is being throttled when out of focus - tab activity can be slowed down by that much.

To get around the problem of tab activity being throttled when a tab does not have the focus, you can use a webworker. For some reason, just having a webworker interacting with the page will override the throttling.

Here is a simple webworker (webworker.js):

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    if (e.data.msg === 'init') {
        setInterval(function() {
            self.postMessage('timer tick');
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

You interact with the webworker from your script like this:

```
    let myworker = new Worker('webworker.js');
    const data = {
        'msg': 'init',
        'currAppVersion': currAppVersion,
        'someOtherVar': 'someMoreData'
    };
    //Send data to webworker
    myworker.postMessage(data);
    //Receive data from webworker
    myworker.onmessage = function (e){
        console.log(e.data);
    }
```

**Here is an SO answer that describes using workers with Tampermonkey scripts:**

[Is it possible to use workers in a Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549779/is-it-possible-to-use-workers-in-a-greasemonkey-script/18691659#18691659)

**And more info:**

https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1050

[How can I load a shared web worker with a user-script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810002/how-can-i-load-a-shared-web-worker-with-a-user-script)

**Resources for learning more about workers in general:**

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/web-workers-in-action-2c9ff33be266/

https://web.dev/articles/workers-basics

https://www.sitepoint.com/developing-faster-javascript-apps-the-ultimate-guide-to-web-workers/

[What can service workers do that web workers cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38632723/what-can-service-workers-do-that-web-workers-cannot)

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` are extremely unreliable when the tab isn't focused, because browsers pause JS execution of tabs that are inactive in order to save resources, which means the `setTimeout` timer gets paused.

Therefore instead of using `setTimeout` for periods longer than, say, 10 minutes, you should use `Date.Now()`, check the current time, then update if necessary. Like this:

This code:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Update should be available if the update period is set to 6 hours. Reloading...');
  localStorage.setItem('updateAttempted', true);
  location.reload();
}, timeUntilUpdateIsAvailable);
```

Should be replaced by this:

```
const nextUpdateTime = Date.now() + timeUntilUpdateIsAvailable;
setInterval(()=>{
   if (Date.now() >= nextUpdateTime){
        console.log('Update should be available if the update period is set to 6 hours. Reloading...');
        localStorage.setItem('updateAttempted', true);
        location.reload();
   }
}, 300000); // Every 5 minutes, we check if the time expired.
```

**Or, if you need even more precision, you can check more precisely by creating a `setTimeout` when it gets close to the end, like this:**

```
const nextUpdateTime = Date.now() + timeUntilUpdateIsAvailable;
const fiveMinutesInMs = 300000;
var updateTimer = setInterval(()=>{
   if (Date.now() >= nextUpdateTime){
        console.log('Update should be available if the update period is set to 6 hours. Reloading...');
        localStorage.setItem('updateAttempted', true);
        location.reload();
   } else {
      //If the update is scheduled to happen within the next five minutes, we use a setTimeout to be more precise.
      if (Date.now() + fiveMinutesInMs >= nextUpdateTime){ 
         clearInterval(updateTimer);
         setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log('Update should be available if the update period is set to 6 hours. Reloading...');
            localStorage.setItem('updateAttempted', true);
            location.reload();
         },nextUpdateTime - Date.now());
      }
   }
}, fiveMinutesInMs); // Every 5 minutes, we check if the time expired.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on how to optimize my timers, but this doesn't answer my question! My timers are precise enough, but after they expire, sometimes the scrip isn't updating even though more than a multiple of 6 hours have passed, and the update peeiod is set to 6 hours in tampermonkey settings.