# In HTML5 does the web worker definition have to be in a seperate *.js file

Tags: html, web-worker

Is there a way to define a web worker inside the body of main html file? Something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var worker = new Worker();// NO URL IS PROVIDED
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    alert("Reply: " + event.data);
}
worker.postMessage("Hello from index.html!");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short:** **Yes** it should be. `Web Workers` run in an isolated thread. As a result, the code that they execute needs to be contained in a separate file. But before we do that, the first thing to do is create a new Worker object in your main page. The constructor takes the name of the worker script:

```
var worker = new Worker('task.js');
```

If the specified file exists, the browser will spawn a new worker thread, which is downloaded asynchronously. The worker will not begin until the file has completely downloaded and executed. If the path to your worker returns an 404, the worker will fail silently.

After creating the worker, start it by calling the `postMessage()` method:

```
worker.postMessage(); // Start the worker.
```

Answer (score 0):

Web workers are completely separate programs. They aren't meant to run that way. So short answer is **yes, they have to be in separate files**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you CAN load a web worker from an absolute URL, string, or another  tag inside the HTML file if using the Blob technique

[Web Worker loading of absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211068/web-worker-loading-of-absolute-url)