# pdf.js and django

Tags: django, pdf.js

pdf.js uses web workers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Specify the main script used to create a new PDF.JS web worker.
    // In production, change this to point to the combined `pdf.js` file.
    PDFJS.workerSrc = '../../src/worker_loader.js';
</script>
```

but as I understand it web workers can't access anything outside of the url that the javascript file came from:

[Can I load a web worker script from an absolute URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549614/can-i-load-a-web-worker-script-from-an-absolute-url)

I'm hosting my site on AWS EC2, but serving my static files from AWS S3.

I therefore get an error when trying to run the equivalent of this line: PDFJS.workerSrc = '../../src/worker_loader.js'; that the .js cannot be loaded.

Have I understood the problem correctly, and if so, what options do I have to get around this?

Comment: What's stopping you from hosting pdf.js files on the same site?

Comment: I'd like to serve most of the static files from aws s3 - is it possible to serve just the pdf.js files from the same server as the main django application and keep the rest on s3?

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be two possible methods. Either turn off the workers:

From a pdf.js [example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765767/async5):

```
// Disable workers to avoid yet another cross-origin issue (workers
// need the URL of // the script to be loaded, and currently do not allow
// cross-origin scripts)
// PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
```

or as suggested by [async5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765767/async5) it is relatively easy to serve pdf.js on the same Apache VirtualHost as Django, with some files served by URLs as static media, and others using the mod_wsgi interface to Django. The documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files) is relatively easy to follow for the apache deployment. For local development the following [snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) added to urls.py is easy to adapt to serve up pdf.js:

```
from django.conf import settings

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

with MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT set appropriately in settings.py

Both will have performance implications.